# prevent the same question from being related

Tags: support, related-questions

In Stack Overflow, it seems like whenever a question is tagged `javascript`, the top question in the Related list is almost always the same [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work), even though most questions are not actually about closures. Why does this question always float to the top, and is there some way to lower its preference?

Comment: *"**Related:** FAQ for Stack Exchange sites"*

Comment: Upvotes above 20 on a question are almost always caused by Redditting.  So, ignore all votes above 20.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ALMOST.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: That is the key word, yes.  But, in general, votes above 20 have nearly zero correlation to question quality.

Comment: @RobertHarvey OK, if you can find me the Reddit for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367392#10367392 , I'll agree with you.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Eeep.. That's an *answer,* not a question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey close enough. Besides, the question has 18...